# iterating through while loop in scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to write a program that will translate a number into its string equivalent. IE 987,654,321 = nine hundred eighty seven million six hundred fifty four thousand three hundred and twenty one.  I read in the value from the console and i want to iterate through a while loop from i = 0 to string.length

example

```
   var s = "987654321"
   var characters = s.toString;
   var i = 0;
   while(i < characters.length){
     do something
   }
```

my code is below

```
    object project1 {
      def main(args: Array[String]) {
        println("Enter a number")
        val s = Console.readLine

        println(eval(s));
      }

      def tens(c: Char) : String = ( 
        if (c.toInt == 9){
          return "Ninety";
        } else if (c.toInt == 8){
          return "Eighty";
        } else if(c.toInt == 7){
          return "Seventy";
        } else if(c.toInt == 6){
          return "Sixty";
        } else if(c.toInt == 5){
          return "Fifty";
        } else if(c.toInt == 4){
          return "Fourty";
        } else if(c.toInt == 3){
          return "Thirty";
        } else if(c.toInt == 2){
          return "Twenty";
        } else{
          return "";
        }
  )

      def everyThingElse(c : Char): String = (
        if (c.toInt == 9){
          return "Nine";
        } else if (c.toInt == 8){
          return "Eight";
        } else if(c.toInt == 7){
          return "Seven";
        } else if(c.toInt  == 6){
          return "Six";
        } else if(c.toInt  == 5){
          return "Five";
        } else if(c.toInt  == 4){
          return "Four";
        } else if(c.toInt  == 3){
          return "Three";
        } else if(c.toInt  == 2){
          return "Two";
        } else if(c.toInt  == 1){
          return "One";
        } else{
          return "";
        }
      );

      def eval(s: String): String = {
        val characters = s.toCharArray;
        var word = "";
        var i = 0;
        while( i < characters.length ){
          if((i == 14) || (i == 11) || (i == 8) || (i == 5) || (i == 2)){
            word = word + everyThingElse(characters(i));
            word = word + " Hundred ";
            i += 1;
          } else if ((i == 13) || (i == 10) || (i == 7) || (i == 4) || (i == 1)){
            if(characters(i).toInt != 1){
              word = word + tens(characters(i));
              i += 1;
            } else{
              i += 1;
              if(characters(i).toInt == 9){
                word = word + " Nineteen ";
              } else if(characters(i).toInt == 8){
                word = word + " Eighteen ";
              } else if(characters(i).toInt ==7){
                word = word + " Seventeen ";
              } else if(characters(i).toInt == 6){
                word = word + " Sixteen ";
              } else if(characters(i).toInt == 5){
                word = word + " Fifteen ";
              } else if(characters(i).toInt == 4){
                word = word + " Fourteen ";
              } else if(characters(i).toInt == 3){
                word = word + " Thirdteen ";
              } else if(characters(i).toInt == 2){
                word = word + " Twelve ";
              } else if(characters(i).toInt == 1){
                word = word + " Ten ";
              }
              i += 1;
            }
          } else if (i == 9){
            word = word + everyThingElse(characters(i));
            word = word + " Billion ";
            i += 1;
          } else if(i == 6){
            word = word + everyThingElse(characters(i));
            word = word + " Million ";
            i += 1;
          } else if (i == 12){
            word = word + everyThingElse(characters(i));
            word = word + " Trillion ";
            i += 1;
          } else if (i == 0){
            word = word + everyThingElse(characters(i));
            i += 1;
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: This question is better suited for CodeReview.

Comment: Sorry was trying to think last night if i had actually posted the issue in this question or not. My problem is when i run this it errors out on the while loop saying found unit expecting string.  This didnt make sense to me probably because im thinking like a java programer and (i) is an int and characters.length should have returned an int atleast thats what i was expecting.  what im trying to understand is how to set a value say i = 0 and loop till the end of an array.  And i had a type-o in the first example 1 of the lines should have read val characters = s.toCharArray;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I decided that this would be fun to have as an output option, so I created:

```
object Longhand {
  val small = (
    " one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve " +
    "thirteen fourteen fifteen sixteen seventeen eighteen nineteen"
  ).split(' ')

  val mid = "twen thir for fif six seven eigh nine".split(' ').map(_ + "ty")

  lazy val big: Stream[String] = {
    Stream("", "thousand") #::: 
    "m b tr quadr quint sext sept oct non dec".split(' ').map(_+"illion").toStream #:::
    big.drop(1).map(_ + "-decillion")
  }

  def duo(n: Int) = {
    if (n >= 20) List(mid(n/10 - 2), small(n % 10)).filterNot(_.isEmpty)
    else List(small(n)).filterNot(_.isEmpty)
  }

  def trio(n: Int, and: Boolean = false) = {
    val tens = duo(n % 100) match {
      case Nil => Nil
      case x => if (and) "and" :: x else x
    }
    List(small(n/100)).filterNot(_.isEmpty).map(_ + " hundred") ::: tens
  }

  def triples(s: String) = s.reverse.grouped(3).map(_.reverse.toInt).toList

  def apply(s: String): String = {
    val and = (s.length>2) #:: Stream.continually(false)
    val tri = (triples(s) zip and).map{ case (s,a) => trio(s,a) }
    val all = (tri zip big).collect{ case (t,b) if !t.isEmpty => t :+ b }
    all.reverse.flatten.filterNot(_.isEmpty).mkString(" ")
  }
  def apply(l: Long): String = if (l<0) "minus "+apply(-l) else apply(l.toString)
  def apply(b: BigInt): String = if (b<0) "minus "+apply(-b) else apply(b.toString)
}
```

which handles arbitrary-length strings.  This has everything and the kitchen sink in it (more suited for code golf than teaching purposes), but perhaps you can take some pointers from it.  In particular, you should try to use lists (arrays, vectors, something) in order to avoid repeating yourself over and over and over and over and over and ....

Ever wonder what the largest unsigned long long (`Long`) is, written out?

```
scala> Longhand(BigInt(2).pow(64)-1)
res32: String = eighteen quintillion four hundred forty six quadrillion
  seven hundred forty four trillion seventy three billion seven hundred nine million
  five hundred fifty one thousand six hundred and fifteen
```

---

Edit: wait, what if you want to solve the inverse problem?  Just insert this after the applies and before the closing brace:

```
val bigset = big.take(12).filterNot(_.isEmpty).toSet
val smallset = small.filterNot(_.isEmpty).toSet
val midset = mid.toSet
val valid = (bigset ++ smallset ++ mid) + "hundred"
val bignum = Iterator.iterate(BigInt(1000))(_ * 1000).take(11).toArray

def unapply(text: String): Option[BigInt] = {
  val bits = text.toLowerCase.trim.split(" +|-").filter(x => !x.isEmpty && x!="and")
  if (!bits.forall(valid contains _)) return None
  val parts = bits.map{ case s =>
    if (bigset contains s) Right(bignum(big.indexOf(s)-1))
    else if (smallset contains s) Left(small.indexOf(s))
    else if (midset contains s) Left(20 + 10*mid.indexOf(s))
    else Left(100)
  }.foldLeft(List[Either[Int,BigInt]]()){ (xs,x) =>
    x match {
      case Left(i) => xs match {
        case Left(j) :: more =>
          if (i==100) {
            if (j>=10) return None else Left(i*j) :: more
          }
          else if (i > 10 && (j%100) != 0) return None
          else if ((j%10) != 0) return None
          else Left(i+j) :: more
        case _ => Left(i) :: xs
      }
      case Right(n) => xs match {
        case Right(m) :: more => Right(n*m) :: more
        case Left(j) :: more => Right(n*j) :: more
        case Nil => Right(n) :: Nil
      }
    }
  }.collect{ case Right(n) => n; case Left(i) => BigInt(i) }
  Some(parts.foldLeft(BigInt(0)){ (acc,x) =>
    if (acc > x) return None else acc+x
  })
}
```

Now you can:

```
scala> "five million eight hundred and one thousand and sixty-two"
res0: String = five million eight hundred and one thousand and sixty-two

scala> res0 match { case Longhand(n) => n }
res1: BigInt = 5801062

scala> Longhand.unapply("one and hundred billion five seven million")
res2: Option[BigInt] = None
```

(There are a few cases where it will accept something that isn't actually properly formatted, but it's pretty good about rejecting ill-formed numbers.)

Comment: Ah ah, awesome. How come you don't even have an account on code golf?

Comment: Doh! Of coures you do. My gosh, you have so many accounts that only a handfull are listed by default on your profile ^^.

Comment: Stream.continually("over") reduce (_ + " and "  + _)

Comment: very interesting never thought about trying to do it that way. I do think this solution is a little beyond the scope of my class and I dont fully understand all of it yet as im new to scala and still learning.

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles - The parser (extractor, i.e. `unapply`) is only an extra 35 lines or so (not shown above).  Look: `scala> "fifty-two thousand eight hundred and ninety-four" match { case Longhand(n) => n }` `res1: BigInt = 52894`

Comment: Nice. You should upload the full code somewhere, for extra awsomeness points.

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles - May as well stick it here, I guess.

Comment: If this is what you get for not asking a question, people should ask fewer questions.

Comment: Sorry i'm the orginal poster and my question was in my code i have a while loop.  the code im concerned with and confused about is        char characters = s.toCharArray  where s is a string; var i = 0; while (i < characters.length).    This keeps throwing an error on the while loop saying type mismatch found unit required string.  I've tried doing while (i < 20) still gives same error. im so confused atm.

Comment: So sorry nvm the error was because i was missing a return value.